# PHP - Processing a Screen Scraped Page

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I have used previous topics on how to scrape a webpage successfully using cURL and PHP. I have managed to get that part working fine, what I need to do is process some information from the page that has no identifiable classes / markup that I can use easily. The example code I have is:

```
<h3>Building details:</h3>
<p>Disabled ramp access<br />
  Male, female and disabled toilets available</p>
  <br/>
  <p><strong>Appointment lead times:</strong></p>
  <p><strong>Type 1</strong>:&nbsp; 8 weeks<br />
  <strong>Type 2</strong>:&nbsp;5 weeks<br />
  <strong>Type 3</strong>:&nbsp;3 weeks<br />
  <strong>Type 4</strong>:&nbsp;3 weeks
</p>
```

What I need to do is get the number of weeks lead time for the different types of appointment, mainly type 1. Sometimes appointment lead times are unavailable and states:

```
<p><strong>Appointment lead times:</strong></p>
<p><strong>Type 1</strong>:&nbsp; No information available<br />
```

I have looked at several methods, RegEx, Simple DOM Parser etc but haven't really got a solution to what I am trying to achieve.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this kind of thing, it can get messy.  You have to find some point in the code to break it apart in a reliable way.  Your sample there has one spot I can see:  `Type 1</strong>:&nbsp;`.  So, I would do this:

`$parts = explode('Type 1</strong>:&nbsp;', $text);`

Now, the first bit of $parts[1] will have either your timeframe, or the no information message.  Let's use the `<br />` at the end to chop it:

```
if (count($parts) == 2) {
  $parts = explode('<br />', $parts[1]);
  $parts = trim(str_replace(' weeks', '', $parts[0]));
}
```

Now, $parts has our message, or our timeframe as a number.  `is_numeric` will show the way!  This is a dirty method, but scraping page data usually is.  Be sure to check the results of each step before assuming you're good for the next.

Comment: Worked like a chram! Thanks a lot. The only thing I had to add to this was a strpos check to make sure the Type x: existed as on some pages it didnt. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

use http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php to convert into valid xml , then you can easily query using xpath via simplexml http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp